# Facebook Messenger like Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to make an app similar to Facebook messenger which has chat heads. I am done with the chat heads part, and now I want to display the window when a user taps on the chat head just like the Messenger. (Look here: http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/fbscreens2.jpg I do not own any of the images)

Can someone tell me how is this done - is it an activity (because i can't see it in my task manager), or a dialog fragment? How can I make something similar which occupies less space than the screen size. Also, my soft keyboard pushes the current white box up and it goes outside the screen space.

What exactly do you call it? I'm new to Android, so please can someone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is mostly called floating windows.
[This article](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) has some great explanations.
And [this one](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/) is more for beginners, with step-by-step instructions.

Here are some libraries, which might already have what you need:

- [klinker24/FloatingWindowDemo](https://github.com/klinker24/FloatingWindowDemo)
- [pingpongboss/StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut)
- [marshallino16/FloatingView](https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView)

Comment: Thank you for the link! I have already seen those chat head basics.. I am done with Chat Head.. Now I need to know how to display that.. Floating windows? Is that what Facebook used?

Comment: Yes, although they are mostly the same, only the latter is bigger and has another form :) I guess you can check the FloatingWindowDemo then.

Comment: One last question.. How can I set the height of the floating window as 80℅ of the screen size?

Comment: See this line: https://github.com/klinker24/FloatingWindowDemo/blob/master/src/com/klinker/android/floating_window/PopupMainActivity.java#L60
You just have to multiply it with 0.8

Comment: How is that Facebook is able to prevent a floating window from showing under the tasks when it is opened? When I click my chat head, my floating window opens, and then when I switch over to the other app, and go to the task manager, I can see my floating window.. How is it happening?

Comment: You can use this library too, it's really simple and straightforward https://github.com/ericbhatti/floaties